# How to change page and hear a sound while changing to next page in android app?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to create an app that has many pages, every page has button.

When I click on the button it takes me to next page.

What i want to do is when I press on the button it plays the sound that i have included in "raw folder?

At this moment when I manipulated the code and I press on the button to change the page it close the app. Can anyone please help. Thanks

here is my code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button button;
MediaPlayer mp;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        MediaPlayer mp;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        mp.seekTo(0);
        mp.start();


    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.test);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainAct2.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }


    });
}

@Override


public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Release the MediaPlayer if going into background
    if(mp != null) mp.release();
} }
```

Comment: Which part you have changed?

Comment: I have added this `
@Override


public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Release the MediaPlayer if going into background
    if(mp != null) mp.release();
} }` and  `mp.seekTo(0);
        mp.start();


    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.test);`

Comment: It seems like your app is closed by an uncaught exception, in that case there is valueable information posted to the device's log. Can you post it as well ([`adb logcat`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html))?

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. What I was able to find out after trying different things and inspections, that as soon as I add this code to start the media player "mp.start();". The app stops. if I remove this the app works fine. without this it wont play a sound for fact. And just to let you know i tried this code in different places just to see what if this works, any how this code is causing to close the app. I'm thinking it does require something else because I'm intent to do 2 things from one method or one button. any help would be appreciated. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If this is how your code is laid out:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    mp.seekTo(0);
    mp.start();

final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.test);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainAct2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Then the reason is because you're trying to use the MediaPlayer before actually initializing it. Try this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        try { 
             final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.test);
             mp.start(); 
        } 
        catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); } // Eat it 
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainAct2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

If that doesn't work, well, something is definitely wrong somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks but the didnt work at all. What I was able to find out after trying different things and inspections, that as soon as I add this code to start the media player "mp.start();". The app stops. if I remove this the app works fine. without this it wont play a sound for fact. And just to let you know i tried this code in different places just to see what if this works, any how this code is causing to close the app. I'm thinking it does require something else because I'm intent to do 2 things from one method or one button.

Comment: If you did what I wrote, it wouldn't crash at all. If your code matches what you wrote in your post, then it's pretty clear you're getting a NullPointerException whenever you click the button because "mp" is always null when you go to use it. You have to initialize it (IE. MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.test);) before you try to use it. You should also post the LogCat.